# Working with some childclass of on a class hierrarchy

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

Imagine this scenario:

```
public class A {
  ...
}

class B extends A {

    public foo getFoo() {
      returns _foo;
    }
}

there also exist other classes children of A having the same method

class C extends A {
     ...
      public foo getFoo() { returns _foo; }
     ...
}

So, the method `foo` doesn't exist in parent class, however, it exists in all children classes. 

Is there a way in Java to not directly specify which child class will be called however use a generic way (I believe in Scala it's [T < A]).

So that I can use it like this:

void Bar(`[some child class of A]` childOfA){
   childOfA.getFoo(); // Now this would return either getFoo() of A or B
}
```

Comment: childofA.getFoo(); // Now this would return either getFoo() of B or C **

Comment: [Edit] your question if you need to make a correction. Maybe fix your formatting too.

Answer (score 0):

That won't be possible with current setup because there is no guarantee that the method will be present in subclasses until unless it's mandated.

Now, what you can do, change parent class, and add `abstract` method there. That will insure, the method is always present in child class or it's further child classes (in case of child class is abstract).

```
abstract class A {
     public abstract Foo getFoo();
}

class C extends A {
   public Foo getFoo(){
     // your code
   }    
}
```

Now, you can have your generic method with an upper bound.

```
void <T extends A> bar(T childOfA){
  childOfA.getFoo();
}
```

Here, `<T extends A>` will make sure, your argument should be subclass of A.